# PfSense Port Forwarding issues

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

I'm having trouble forwarding a port through PfSense
PF WAN: 192.168.254.203
PF LAN: 10.0.0.1
Dest: 10.0.0.6

PfSense is able to ping and ssh .0.6 from local shell, test port works on LAN, but testing from WAN (and attempting ssh over 3g) fails. At a loss, any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first WAN rule you have (allowing SSH to the WAN address). You should only need the rule allowing SSH to 10.0.0.6 and the NAT port forwarding rule to forward to 10.0.0.6

Also, best practice if you're actually using this for SSH would be to limit the protocol on those rules to TCP, which is what SSH uses.